# android studio layout view is empty

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I create a new project for my android app. But the layout view is all white and empty. This is the image [image: 1]

but compare to what others have

[image: 2]

It clearly sees that my layout window does not have a blue title on top, time and battery.

Comment: Show us your code. My guess is that you are in full screen mode

Comment: show us ur style.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check on `Show Layout Decorations` from your `Activity` Design tab.
This will fix previews..

Click on the eye icon visible upper side, it'll expand and just check on that item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a design view only so first run your application and check whether toolbar is there or not.

if its still not coming
Go to **style.xml** and change your theme.

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

There are several themes, you can choose accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is you updated your android studio to 3.3
and I know there is the change that title bar will not visible in android design tab but if you run your app in the emulator or real device it will there

you don't have to change the theme or anything run your app it will be there in your device

I hope this will help you